# Python 3.6 Discord Bot Cooldown message

Tags: python, bots, discord

so I have this command which allows the user to change the game and it works perfectly but I put a 15 second cooldown on it and it too works fine, but my issue is getting it to display a message that you are in cooldown period OR if the command has successfully executed. I'm new to python and this is probably a simple fix so I apologize for wasting your time, but thx in advance

My code:

```
@client.command(name="status")
@commands.cooldown(1, 15, commands.BucketType.server)
async def client_status(*, status: str = None):
    """Change the bot's 'playing' status.
    Running this command without any arguments will turn the 'playing'     status off'
    """
    game = Game(name=status)
    await client.change_presence(game=game)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a member tries to invoke a command that is currently on cooldown a [CommandOnCooldown](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cooldown#discord.ext.commands.CommandOnCooldown) exception is thrown and triggers [on_command_error](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cooldown#discord.on_command_error).

Although async does not document it there is an event `on_command_completion`

```
on_command_completion(command, ctx)
```

this is dispatched if a command has successfully completed its invocation.