# Cooldown For on_message On Discord Bot Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.guild.id == 464298877823221761:
        if message.content.find("Hello There") != -1:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
            await message.channel.send("General Kenobi")
```

I want to set a 30 sec cooldown for this

Entire Cog: https://hastebin.com/isuxokizum.py

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48485434/python-3-6-discord-bot-cooldown-message

Comment: this is not a command

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you're other part of code so I don't know if you want/need/got some ansynchronous programming.
If not you could also try `time.sleep(30)` - it just freezes the execution of your code

---

> ```
> time.sleep(5)
> ```
>
> ...freezes the execution of your code for 5 seconds. Nothing further
> is computed or executed until the sleep function has completed it's 5
> second nap as the application can't proceed without the sleep function
> returning control to the caller. This is called synchronous
> programming, when there is no mechanism for the application to change
> its focus and complete other tasks in periods of waiting such as
> waiting for the results of a call to a database, a web api or as in
> this case the sleep function. In synchronous programming there is no
> need for an event loop as there is no expectation that the application
> manages its time nor that it switches tasks for efficiency gains.

---

> ```
> asyncio.sleep(5)
> ```
>
> ... is part of the asyncio library, designed
> for asynchronous programming where an event loop is assigned tasks to
> be competed and it (the event loop) monitors the state of all its
> tasks and switches from one to another with the objective of
> minimising the amount of time idle/waiting. This is not threading
> where multiple processes are being executed simultaneously, this is
> merely optimising task execution so the CPU is not left idle,
> therefore gaining hugely reduced overall execution times.

Comment: This is the entire cog https://hastebin.com/isuxokizum.py